projecting the Grid grid onto the model
I want to project a Grid onto my model in geometry nodes. Here I want to rotate the Grid by Z to choose the direction of the bars. I tried to implement it myself, but it didn't work.


Your images are fantastic however, your words seem to be missing some context. The target seems to be a flat, single faced mesh that you want to project to. However, a Model does not necessarily mean it has one face to work with. Likewise, cutting your mesh into strips is different from projecting a grid onto it. If what you're calling a Grid is an intricate tessellation pattern, then this entire question may actually be a very, difficult subdivision problem.
